# what is the proper way to use HighCharts or ChartJS with angular-meteor

Tags: angular-meteor

I was researching a way if using a charting library with angular-meteor application. I have seen some examples of using HighCharts with AngylarJS. I have also seen examples of using HighCharts with Meteor. I would love to be able to use either HighCharts or ChartJS within angular-meteor application, and to have my charts data bound to Angular $scope, but, at the some time, have those charts react to the data changes in the server-side MongoDB (which us what Meteor does). I have seen some examples of angular-meteor app, but never seen such an app use any charts. Can anyone point me to a working angular-meteor example, which has a reactive chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [angular directive for chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). Here is a simple example showing a pie chart:

Starting from a Meteor 1.3 template application (run `meteor create myapp`).
Replace `blaze-html-templates` with `angular-templates` in `.meteor/packages`,
add

```
"angular": "^1.5.5",
"angular-chart.js": "0.10.2",
"angular-meteor": "^1.3.10",`
```

to "dependencies" in `package.json`, run `meteor npm install`, replace the content of `client/main.js` with this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css';
import 'angular-chart.js';

angular.module('app', [
  'chart.js'
]).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.labels = ["a", "b", "c"];
  $scope.data = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

and the content of `client/main.html` with this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
 </body>
```

run `meteor`.

You should see the pie chart. Obviously you can replace the data variable with some data from a collection etc. using Meteor. Here we haven't really used meteor except of the command line tool.