# How to get mongodb data on my angular controller to draw a chart

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm new to meteor/mongodb and i'm building an app using meteor-angular.

Everything is working fine, i've my collection on the server which is subscribed to the client so that the client minimongo is filed with the proper data, Data that can be accessed and iterated over in my view using angular helpers such as  [docs](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding) :

```
 angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.helpers({
      parties: () => {
        return Parties.find({});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

My question is , how can i use the client minimongo data inside my angular controller ?

I've tried fetching and console logging , but can only get either undefined / empty array / mongo db cursor object , whereas what i'm looking for is more of a JSON data from the query so that i can do something with it in my angular controller.

I could implement a simple server side API the would send just the required data and that would certainly works, but it seems like having the same data twice since the client already is subscribed to that data which is perfectly usable inside my view.

Any idea how to do something like this ?

Edit:

My data is binded to my angular view already, I have a collection on the server with a publish method ,the same one on the client and the data is subscribed from the server so i can access it in my view using the helper( parties in the previous example ).This issue is since the data is syncronized with the view/client throught mini mongo i can't really acces it before hand using my controller.

console log($scope.parties give undefined / mongo cursor)

I'm trying to get data from my subscribed collection on the client controller so that i can draw a chart from this data using chartjs/highcharts. I've already tried to acces the data after document ready but to no success :(

Last resort as i said would be calling an api on my server from my client controller and use the data from there. But it feels like there would be a better way since the data is already accessible from the view.

The chartjs code is as follow :

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
  $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt);
  };
});
```

So i would need to get the data from the subscribe as $scope.data to bind it reactively to my chart. ( it's the same issue with highcharts even if it seems way easier using highcharts + blaze ).

closest question i could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543848/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-highcharts-or-chartjs-with-angular-meteor) but since no one answered i've figured i would try a slightly lower level..

Comment: Have you seen the code examples in this blog post? They're what I used to get started with that https://www.codementor.io/meteor/tutorial/why-you-should-use-angular-meteor-library

Comment: @user697 can you provide an example how do you try to use data on client? Before use any data on client you should call $scope.subscribe() to get data from server app.